# Bluestacks on windows10 once worked well and then failed and stucks in initializing the next time i started i

Tags: initialization, windows-10, whatsapp, bluestacks

i installed bluestacks on my windows 10 laptop (HP elitebook ) , it worked well the first time , i installed whatsapp on it ,it worked properly for few minitues messages started flowing but i couldnt get the chance to read them because my laptop frozes for seconds so i restarded it, the next time i started bluestacks after opening the laptop i found that it went back to initializing phase, i'm forever stuck there. 
i'm not sure if it needs a good internet to initialize 
for the second time? 
if not , why it stucks in initializing , i tried multiple suggestions i found on internet (like compatibility solution) but didnt work out. 
if there is nothing to do, how can i extract whatsapp database so i can read my chats on another device. 
if i installed whatsapp on another device, i won't get the messages i recieved once on bluestack again,right?
please help me whatsapp chats are so important to me.

Answer (score -3):

you can't able to restore those chats again

if you are using windows 10 directly download whats app to your lap directly from store or go to link https://www.whatsapp.com/download/

Comment: i wont get the messages even after overcoming the initializing issue?? oh noo

Comment: all those data will be saved in temp after every restart of app you will lose every data